# Como cerrar un WebView automaticamente despues de cierto evento(Android)?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview-android

Estoy trabajando con formularios de `TypeForm` que los muestro a través de `WebView` en mi aplicación.

Lo que estoy intentando realizar es cerrar el `WebView` después de que terminan el formulario.

Cuando se termina el formulario en pantalla aparece un texto agradeciendo.
Como podre tomar ese texto y en el caso que aparezca cerrar el WebView.

**Este es el codigo que tengo hecho.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_form_rest_of_day);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("");

    Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    assert datos != null;
    user = datos.getString("email");

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")) {

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://cliente.typeform.com/to/U0mcRV?user=" + user);
    }else{

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://cliente.typeform.com/to/U7o3PU?user=" + user);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    } else
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Saludos!

Comment: necesitar comunicar javascript con android , https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/android-mixed-native-web/

Comment: @diegoveloper muchas gracias! Pero sigo sin poder conseguirlo. No logro darme cuenta como tomar ese texto de agradecimiento y que se cierre el typeForm.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes realizar en este caso es modificar la visibilidad del `WebView` para "cerrarlo", cuando detectes la finalización del formulario realiza esto para desaparecerlo:

```
myWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

y esto para aparecerlo:

```
myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```